# Same data, different PACF? [R vs Stata]

Tags: r, data-visualization, stata, autocorrelation

So I was playing around with R, trying to figure out how to do basic time series stuff. Using the Box-Jenkins Series G ("airline passengers") data, I wanted to plot ACF and PACF. So here's my code:

```
library(foreign)
bjg <- read.dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r9/air2.dta")
airline.ts <- ts(bjg[, 1], start=c(1949,1), freq=12) 

layout(1:2)
acf(airline.ts,ci.type="ma",lag.max=40)
pacf(airline.ts,lag.max=40)
```

But then compare the same graphs from Stata, using the *same* data set.

[image]

While the ACFs look alike, the PACFs are clearly different between R and Stata. How can that be? Where's my mistake?

P.S.: Here's the Stata code:

```
webuse air2
tsset t
ac air
pac air
```

Comment: You graphs say air, not lnair on the y-axis. Are you sure the Stata code is correct?

Comment: Try adding `, yw`  option in the pac command to have the partial autocorrelations be calculated using the Yule-Walker equations instead of using the default regression-based technique.

Comment: You're right, I did in fact tested air in those graphs. I tested lnair, too. Sorry for messing up the code.
As for your other answer, the `, yw` option in Stata indeed produces the same graphs. Thank you. Now is there in option _in R_ to produce the PACF with the regression-based technique?

Comment: The method is in the [Stata documentation](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/tscorrgram.pdf) and is pretty straigforward. I am not aware of an R implementation, but one may well exist. You might modify your question rather than asking in the comments.